Гарантирует ли Boost Serealization безопасность десериализации?
Например, клиент сериализовал std::vector, std::unordered_map, boost::optional, std::shared_ptr или иной другой тип, механизм сериализации которого изложен непосредственно в Boost, после чего отправляет его серверу. Сервер получает этот пакет и десериализовывает его, при необходимости ловля boost::archive::archive_exception и отбрасывая пакет. Гарантирует ли такой подход, что сервер не рухнет с каким-нибудь SIGSEGV в момент попытки десериализации (внутри блока try) или уже при последующей работе с десериализованными структурами, даже если человек на клиенте очень постарается?

Кажется, гарантии нет: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69207348/276994
